# Can't implement before_save filter (when checking data that doesn't go to db)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I need to verify User data before_save. I'm saving only paypal_email, and don't save first and last name.

I added before_save filter in my model:

```
   attr_accessible :paypal_email, :first_name, :last_name
   attr_accessor :first_name
   attr_accessor :last_name

   before_save :verify
```

and added veify method:

```
   protected
 def verify

require 'httpclient'
require 'xmlsimple'

clnt = HTTPClient.new

header =  {"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "1111111111",
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "111111",
               "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "11111",
               "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NV",
               "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "XML",
               "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" =>  "APP-2J632856DC989803F"
                }
 logger.info(@user.first_name)               
 data = {"emailAddress" => self.paypal_email,
       "firstName"=> self.first_name,
       "lastName" => self.last_name,
       "matchCriteria" => "NAME",         
       "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US"}

 uri = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"
 res = clnt.post(uri, data, header)
 @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)

  if res.status == 200
    if @xml['accountStatus']!=nil
      account_status = @xml['accountStatus'][0]
      if account_status == "VERIFIED" 
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:success] = "Your account is verified"
      else 
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = res.content
      end

    else
      redirect_to :back
       flash[:error] = res.content
   end  
   else 
    flash[:error] = "Oops! Can't conntect to PayPal"
  end

 end
```

**EDIT**

```
    def create
     @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.valid?
         @user.save
         flash[:notice] = "success"
     else
         render :new
         flash[:error] = "error"

 end
```

what give me error:

```
     undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Where is my error ?

Comment: why do you require files inside the method?

Comment: @apneadiving I need them to build xml. Where I should require them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in your model, replace `@user.first_name` with `self.first_name` or even `first_name`

Other issues

- third party service calls should live in background jobs.
- point `flash` is unknown in models, it belongs to controller, as well as `redirect`.
- redirect_to :back, is not that a good practice: some browsers don't send the referrer

Comment: it should be: `"first_name"=> params[:user][:first_name], "last_name" => params[:user][:last_name]`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But where I should call `flash[:notice]` ?

Comment: I want `if account_status == "VERIFIED" 
            @user.save` in this method, but it is wrong. How it should be ?

Comment: in controller, if your object validation fails for instance

Comment: `@user.save if account_status == "VERIFIED"` looks more like valid ruby code

Comment: once again, in your model use `self` not `@user` and it doesn't make sens to call save in a `before_save`

Comment: Yeah, it is right about `self` Look at my suggestion in question.

Comment: if `@user.save` will do the same, no need to check for valid object, it's automatic

Comment: apneadiving, it is constantly says, that details are verified, even when they'are not(

Comment: in a `before_save` filter, return false to end the chain, actually you'd rather use some custom validator

Comment: Something like `if account_status != "VERIFIED" 
            return false
          end` but it didn't work for me

Comment: yes. I already answered 4 questions instead of 1, I consider I'm done with this one

Comment: Can you give me example of validator ?